# How to copy files from a folder using the find command with the -exec action, or with xargs, to another folder

Tags: command-line, find, cp, xargs

I'd like to use the find command with the -exec action with the plus (+) sign (for efficiency), or with xargs to copy files from one directory to another.
The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368872/how-to-move-or-copy-files-listed-by-find-command-in-unix) answer did not work for me.
I'm under bash version: 4.3.48(1).
Trying:

```
find . \( \( -type f -size -2M \) -o \( -type f -size 2M \) \) -exec cp '{}' ~/Pictures/test_folder '+'
```

or:

```
find . \( -type f -size -2M \) -o \( -type f -size 2M \) | xargs cp -t ~/Pictures/test_folder
```

does not work for me. Maybe I've made a syntactic error of some kind, but I've already tried several variations of the above commands and I still can't get it to work. The test folder is the location where I'd like the files to be copied to.

Comment: Do you get an error? "Does not work" is not enough information,

Comment: Yes. If I enter the first command, I get: `find: missing argument to -exec` If I enter the second command, I get a message error for each file, i.e. `cp: cannot stat './file1': No such file or directory`, and only one file gets copied into the test folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd expect this to work:

```
find . -type f \( -size -2M -o -size 2M \) -exec cp -t ~/Pictures/test_folder {} +
```

(I took out the common `-type f` test.)

With `+`, the `{}` is expected to be the last item in an `-exec` command. From [the GNU find manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files):

> Only one `{}` is allowed within the command, and it must appear at the
>   end, immediately before the `+`. A `+` appearing in any position other
>   than immediately after `{}` is not considered to be special (that is,
>   it does not terminate the command).

If you use `find` and `xargs`, remember to use the `-print0` and `-0` options:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t ...
```

With `-print0`, filenames are delimited with the ASCII NUL character, the only one not allowed in paths. Without this, `xargs` could split filenames on spaces, so a `./file1 - foo.txt` would be seen as `./file1`, `-` and `foo.txt` by the `cp` command.

Comment: So that means the comment in the link I provided about putting the `{}` before the pathname of the cp command was definitely wrong, assuming they were using GNU find. What I'd like to know now is how I do the same thing but with the `xargs` command.

Comment: @John_Patrick_Mason which comment are you talking about? No comment or answer uses `-exec cp {} ... +`. It's either `-exec cp -t ... {} +` or `-exec cp {} ... \;`. As for `xargs`, see edit.

Comment: You're right, but to be fair the third comment in the link should have been more specific instead of telling the OP to just add `+;` to the end of the command.

Comment: Thanks muru, that solved my problem. I'm marking this as solved.